# Leaflet filtering by property loaded with geoCsv

Tags: dictionary, filter, leaflet, geojson

i'm trying to filter loaded values depending from the property. I have added a filter function, but I get no matches shown on th map.

```
var crimeeventsb = L.geoCsv(null, {
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    var popup = '';
    for (var clave in feature.properties) {
        var title = crimeevents.getPropertyTitle(clave);
        popup += '<b>'+title+'</b><br />'+feature.properties[clave]+'<br /><br />';
    }
    layer.bindPopup(popup);
},
filter: function(feature, layer){
    return feature.properties.Provincia == "Valencia";
},

pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.marker(latlng, {
        icon:L.icon({
            iconUrl: './data/wed.png',
            shadowUrl: './data/marker-shadow.png',
            iconSize: [41,41],
            shadowSize:   [41, 41],
            shadowAnchor: [13, 20]
        })
    });
},


firstLineTitles: true
```

});

has someone a hint?

Cheers,

Karsten

More Informations:

My csv look like this:

Dirección;Código postal;Localidad;Provincia;Teléfono;time;lat;lng
Acceso Ademúz, S/N;46100;Burjassot;Valencia;963638421;01.01.2014;39.51;-0.425055

Here is the code I how I want to add the markers:

```
$.ajax ({
type:'GET',
dataType:'text',
url:'./data/daten_new.csv',
error: function() {
alert('Achtung! Es konnten keine Daten gefunden werden!');
},
success: function(csv) {


 /* var cluster = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
    crimeevents.addData(csv);
    cluster.addLayer(crimeevents);
    karte.addLayer(cluster);
    karte.fitBounds(cluster.getBounds());
*/



crimeeventsb.addData(csv);
karte.addLayer(crimeeventsb);
```

}

Build it in jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/krank42/qgvradgk/

Comment: Can you add the code where you are adding the markers to the map and where you are calling filter from?

Comment: I added it in the question.

Comment: Looks like you followed this [example](http://joker-x.github.io/Leaflet.geoCSV/example/bankia/index.html). Is it even hitting your crimeeventsb.addData(csv);? Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes I did. But how can I filter the "Provincia"?

Comment: First step would be to just get everything on the map. Is it even hitting your crimeeventsb.addData(csv);? Can you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example?

Comment: If I don't filter I could add all markers with crimeeventsb.addData(csv);! I will later create a jsfiddle.

Comment: It seems to me your jsfiddle example has cross-domain problem. The page and script are hosted on one domain and you are trying to fetch csv file from the other domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having a typo. Change

```
filter: function(feature, layer){
return feature.properties.Provincia == "Valencia";
```

},

to

```
filter: function(feature, layer){
return feature.properties.provincia == "Valencia";
```

},

Note that capital P in Provincia should be changed to p.